# Reverse DNS does not contain the hostname

Tags: email, dns, smtp, whm, exim

I use a Centos Server in Windows HyperV. When I was sent a mail over this server, I get an error mail.

```
This message was created automatically by mail delivery software.

A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:

  serefseven@gmail.com
    host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [66.102.1.26]
    SMTP error from remote mail server after end of data:
    550-5.7.1 [185.124.86.138] The IP address sending this message does not have a
    550-5.7.1 PTR record setup. As a policy, Gmail does not accept messages from
    550-5.7.1 IPs with missing PTR records. Please visit
    550-5.7.1  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126#authentication for more
    550 5.7.1 information. y187si26143569wmc.112 - gsmtp
Reporting-MTA: dns; ln1.postoflscell.com

Action: failed
Final-Recipient: rfc822;serefseven@gmail.com
Status: 5.0.0
Remote-MTA: dns; gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550-5.7.1 [185.124.86.138] The IP address sending this message does not have a
 550-5.7.1 PTR record setup. As a policy, Gmail does not accept messages from
 550-5.7.1 IPs with missing PTR records. Please visit
 550-5.7.1  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126#authentication for more
 550 5.7.1 information. y187si26143569wmc.112 - gsmtp
```

mxtollbox.com smtp test result :

SMTP Reverse DNS Mismatch   Reverse DNS does not contain the hostname

SMTP Banner Check   Reverse DNS does not match SMTP Banner

SMTP TLS    Warning - Does not support TLS.

SMTP Transaction Time   15.485 seconds - Not good! on Transaction Time

SMTP Valid Hostname OK - Reverse DNS is a valid Hostname

SMTP Connection Time    0 seconds - Good on Connection time

SMTP Open Relay OK - Not an open relay.

how to fix this problem?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

As the error states, `The IP address sending this message does not have a PTR record setup`, so you need to set the PTR record for `185.124.86.138` (it is quite usual that receiving mail server requires [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup#Uses)). Reverse DNS is controlled by whoever "owns" the IP address, so you should probably contact [Bilgehosting](http://whois.domaintools.com/185.124.86.138) to set the record for you)